# norm of $ | \nabla X|^2 $ in coordinates form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I want to find a formula in coordinates-form for $ | \nabla X|^2 $ where $|\nabla|$ is the Levi-Civita connection and $X$ is a vector field. I know that $|X|^2= g(X,X)$ can be written as $X^2= g_{ij} X^iX^j$ and $\nabla X$  leads to $\partial_i X^j + \Gamma^j_{il} X^k$ but I can't find a way to apply this to $ | \nabla X|^2 $